# Can i access a TCP|IP socket in google chrome of user's own system ? even with grant permission of user?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i want to try a application (chrome app) who need to access socket (port) of user's system.

can i do it. i just want to give them utility for the software they installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do this very easily.  WebSockets do provide socket support, but won't really give you the functionality you are looking for here.

There are some super complex ways of solving this, for example using C/C++ and the like, but would be extremely time consuming to write and maintain.  You could also write a proxy that would be able to convert the raw socket connections to an HTTP request or WebSocket request, but again, lots of work.